# Questions about William's Heapsort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

If I'm not mistaken, the current implementations of `heapsort` use a modified version called `treesort`. I'm trying to understand the original algorithm as written by [Williams](https://doi.org/10.1145%2F512274.512284).

`OUTHEAP` is called by `SWOPHEAP` who is never called. How does the algorithm work then? Is the replacement of a `min heap` by a `max heap` the only difference between this algorithm and the pseudocode found in every book?

Comment: No, [tree sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort) does not use a heap data structure, but a binary *search* tree, and is therefore not heap sort.

Comment: I wrote the bad name. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You express multiple doubts/questions, so let me address them one by one:

> If I'm not mistaken, the current implementations of heapsort use a modified version called treesort.

This is what you would conclude if you read the 1963-1964 papers by Williams, Floyd. Floyd used the name `TREESORT` for an improvement on the novelty found by Williams, who called the data structure a heap, and the sorting algorithm heap sort. The terminology has since evolved.

Now we would consider both heapsort. Floyd essentially [improved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Floyd%27s_heap_construction) William's `SETHEAP` function so it would run more efficiently, but called his function `TREESORT 3`. When today we refer to [tree sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort), we mean something different: that is a sorting algorithm that uses a binary *search* tree as data structure, which has different properties than a binary heap data structure.

> `OUTHEAP` is called by `SWOPHEAP` who is never called. How does the algorithm work then?

It was not William's purpose to use `SWOPHEAP` for his novel heap sort algorithm. He first introduced the concept of a heap (not yet the sorting algorithm), and provided a few utility functions to work with such a heap: `SETHEAP`, `INHEAP`, `OUTHEAP` and `SWOPHEAP`. Note that the wikipedia article on the [heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation) discusses the same operations and calls them construction (`SETHEAP`), insertion (`INHEAP`), extraction (`OUTHEAP`) and replacement (`SWOPHEAP`).

After having introduced the concept of a heap and these functions to work with them, Williams continued:

> The procedures may be used for replacement-selection sorting, for sorting the elements of an array, or for choosing the current minimum of any set of items to which new items are added from time to time.

He didn't claim that for *all* these purposes, *all* these utility functions had to be used. For the last example of application you would use `SWOPHEAP` and as it turns out, you don't need it for implementing heap sort.

> Is the replacement of a min heap by a max heap the only difference between this algorithm and the pseudocode found in every book?

Certainly not "every book" introduces heaps in the same way. Some introduce the concept with a min heap implementation, while others will a max heap for that purpose.

A min heap may be a bit more natural to start with, since a heap can be seen as a kind of "partially sorted" collection, and for sorting, we also consider the default to be from least to greater (by convention).

But realise that in order to use heap sort for sorting in that non-descending order, you actually need a max heap! If in heap sort you would use a min heap, you would end up with a list that is sorted from great to small.

Comment: So what Floyd called ``TREESORT 3`` is what we call ``heapsort``? I didn't get the last paragraph you wrote but I think that's due to the fact that I don't get how the original algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: Yes, what Floyd called `TREESORT 3` is what we call heap sort. It is what Wikipedia lists as a [variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Floyd's_heap_construction), and Floyd's improvement only concerns the *construction* of a heap data structure. It did not make relevant changes to how that heap is used for the *sorting* algorithm. It is important to realise that the heap data structure and heap sort are two different things. Heapsort needs to construct a heap (which Floyd improved), and then apply the sorting algorithm, which is mostly William's work.